# Finding the point in a circle that creates the largest angle with center of circle and one other point

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Being given two points $A$ and $B$, find the point $P$ such that $DistanceBetween(A, P) \le 1$ and the angle $\angle ABP$ is as big as possible.

If you look at the picture in the example it would seem as if there are two such points $P$, one on the upper half of the circle and one on the bottom half.

It would be appreciated if you can find a way of doing this that uses the least amount of post "high school, early college" math.

**Here is an example:**

There are two points $A = (2, 0)$ and $B = (-1, 0)$.
Find the point $P$ such that $DistanceBetween(A, P) \le 1$ and the angle $\angle ABP$ is as big as possible.
[image]

Comment: $BP$ must be the tangent and this is why there are two points.

Comment: @Raffaele Wait, isnt this the anwer then? The tangent from $B$ to the circle gives the greatest angle?
But how do i express this angle symbollicaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assume that $|AB|>1$.
Let $P_1,P_2$ be the intersections of the circle $c_1$ around $A$ of radius 1 and the circle $c_2$  with $AB$ as diameter. By Thales applied to $c_2$, $\angle AP_iB=90^\circ$ so that the lines $BP_i$ are tangent to $c_1$.
Then the circle $c_1$ (including its interior) is fully between the two rays $BP_i$. Hence for any valid $P$, $\angle ABP$ is between $\angle ABP_1$ and $ABP_2$, inclusive (with equality iff $P=P_i$), hence in absolute value at most as large as when we actually pick $P=P_i$.

If $|AB|<1$, we can of course achieve $\angle ABP=180^\circ$.

If $|AB|=1$, we must agree how to treat the degenerate case $P=B$. If we disallow $P=B$, we can approach $90^\circ $ as closely as we desire.